# Find all positive integers $ a $ and $ b $ such that $7^a-3(2^b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

I am looking for all positive integers satisfying the equation
$$7^a-3(2^b)=1$$

I used the fact that $ (1,1) $ is a solution and got
$$(7^a-7)=3(2^b-2)$$
I thaught about using Gauss Theorem in vain.
Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: OP is apparently using the decimal point as a multiplication sign

Comment: What are the factors you can identify on each side?

Comment: @RossMillikan You mean $ 7 $ and $ 6$ .

Comment: $7^2-3\cdot2^4=1$ is another solution.

Comment: Cf. [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1768357p11591494)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking from your precious time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints:

> If $b\geq 3$ then $$(-1)^a \equiv_8 1 \implies a \equiv_2 0$$ so $a=2c$ and now we have $$(7^c-1)(7^c+1)=3\cdot 2^b$$

> Clearly, since $7^c-1$ and $7^c+1$ are two consecutive even numbers exactly one is not divisible by $4.$

Hope you can finish now.

Comment: Sorry, still don't see how to end it.

Comment: Since $c\geqslant1$ and $7^c+1$ is not divisible by $3$, then $7^c+1\geqslant8$ is a power of $2$ and is divisible by $4$, whereas $7^c-1$ is even not divisible by $4$, is divisible by $3$ and does not contain other prime factors apart from $2$ and $3$. Consequently $7^c-1=6$, hence $c=1$, $a=2$, $b=4$. It means that $(a,b)=(2,4)$ is a solution. If $b\leqslant2$ there is only another solution that is $(a,b)=(1,1)$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah If exactly one of $(7^c-1)$ and $(7^c11)$ is divisible by $4$, the other must be a divisor of $6$.

Answer (score 2):

An argument mod $7$ shows that $b+2$ is divisible by $3$, then let $b=3n-2.$
We can take the two cases $a=2m, a=2m+1.$
The problem can be reduced to finding the integer points on elliptic curves as follows.

$\bullet\ a=2m$
Let $X=3\cdot2^{n}, Y=6\cdot7^{m}$, then we get
$Y^2 =X^3 + 36.$
According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/972/a/2), this elliptic curve has integral solutions $(X,Y)=(-3,\pm 3), (0,\pm 6), (4,\pm 10), (12,\pm 42).$
From $(12,\pm 42)$ we get $(m,n)=(1,2) \implies (a,b)=(2,4).$

$\bullet\ a=2m+1$
Let $X=21\cdot2^{n}, Y=294\cdot7^{m}$, then we get
$Y^2 =X^3 + 12348.$
According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/190512/ci/2), this elliptic curve has integral solutions $(X,Y)=(-14,\pm 98), (-3,\pm 111), (21,\pm 147), (37,\pm 251), (42,\pm 294), (378,\pm 7350), (11802,\pm 1282134).$
From $(42,\pm 294)$ we get $(m,n)=(0,1) \implies (a,b)=(1,1).$

Hence there are only integral solutions $(a,b)=(1,1),(2,4).$

Comment: Thanks to all if you, for your help.